# Calculation on a vector of values in a R data.table

Tags: r, datatable, aggregate, data-wrangling

I have the following data.table in R:

```
dataset <- data.table(C=c("a", "b", "c") , neg=c("5, 7", "9", "3, 4, 5"), pos = c("5.05, 8", "", "2.95, 4.2"))
```

the table looks like this:

[image: example data.table]

I want to find an overlap between the values in the columns “neg” and “pos”.
If the difference between any value in the two columns in the same row is smaller than **0.1** - I want to merge the values by taking the mean of the two values.
E.g. for the pair 5 and 5.05 – 5.025 should be calculated. If there is no value within the same 0.1 range just the original value is shown. I added a picture of my idea of a possible result:

[image: possible result table]

Is there a function to do this directly or do I have to split/ rearrange the table before?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are stored as character values so first you need to split them on comma, convert them to numeric, `sort` the data. You can then calculate the difference between consecutive values and combine the two values (by taking their average) if their difference is less than 0.1.

In base R, with `Map` and `tapply` you can do -

```
dataset$overlap <- Map(function(x, y) {
  p <- sort(as.numeric(c(x, y)))
  as.numeric(tapply(p, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(p) > 0.1)), mean))
}, strsplit(dataset$neg, ',\\s*'), strsplit(dataset$pos, ',\\s*'))

dataset

#   C     neg       pos                 overlap
#1: a    5, 7   5.05, 8       5.025,7.000,8.000
#2: b       9                                 9
#3: c 3, 4, 5 2.95, 4.2 2.975,4.000,4.200,5.000

dataset$overlap

#[[1]]
#[1] 5.025 7.000 8.000

#[[2]]
#[1] 9

#[[3]]
#[1] 2.975 4.000 4.200 5.000
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In the example in the question there are no values within 0.1 of each other within any input cell and we assume that that is the general case or if not then it is ok to coalesce those too.

For each row scan the numbers into a numeric vector, sort it and find the instances where adjacent numbers are less than 0.1 .  Take the mean of those numbers and NA out the prior number.  Omit the NA's and convert to a comma separated string.

If the values in C are unique then we could replace the by= with by=C.

```
dataset[, overlap := {
  s <- sort(scan(text = c(neg, pos), sep = ",", quiet = TRUE))
  wx <- which(c(FALSE, diff(s) < 0.1))
  s[wx] <- (s[wx] + s[wx-1]) / 2
  s[wx-1] <- NA
  toString(na.omit(s))
}, by = 1:nrow(dataset)]

dataset
##    C     neg       pos          overlap
## 1: a    5, 7   5.05, 8      5.025, 7, 8
## 2: b       9                          9
## 3: c 3, 4, 5 2.95, 4.2 2.975, 4, 4.2, 5
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right: in one input cell there are no values within 0.1 of each other (just between the pos/ neg cols). One question: how can I use the names of the colums (pos/ neg) in your code? I tried to replace the 1/-1 in the apply function but it did not work. FOr the example code it worked well!

Comment: Have modified it to use pos and neg and remove the apply.  I don't understand the part of the comment that refers to 1/-1.

Comment: Alright! Thanks - now it works also with the col. names.